# Replace wireless driver with modprobe

Tags: 13.04, wireless, networking, drivers, kernel

This question, like many others here, regards the rt2800pci driver with a Realtek 539a adapter on the HP ProBokk 4540 (related bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1049466)).

I have followed the steps on many other posts, such as the solution in the last post here:

[Wifi keeps disconnecting and extremely slow at low signal - Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295035/wifi-keeps-disconnecting-and-extremely-slow-at-low-signal-ubuntu-13-04)

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 with the 3.11-1 kernel. I compiled the MediaTek driver (with patch) as prescribed, and all went well. The problem came in the last part, where I am supposed to add the new rt5390sta module to my modules list.

```
sudo modprobe rt5390sta
lsmod
```

This executes, and I see the module loaded. I have also blacklisted the old rt2800 modules as the solution prescribes. However, wlan0 refuses to come back up.

If I can get this to work, it will save 60-some student and teacher laptops a very troublesome adapter replacement.

Comment: Are you sure your device is coming back up as wlan0 ?
run "ifconfig -a" from a command prompt

Answer (score 0):

First execute the following commands to install the packages

sudo apt-get install linux-libc-dev libc6-dev linux-firmware-nonfree

Then run this command

sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source

then run this command

sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-lpphy-installer

Now reboot and try it

If that fails then do this

It should defintely help you. I like to use WICD because it is a simple and easy to use network manager. Its a very good alternative to network manager in Ubuntu and it seems to always work when Network Manager doesn't. To install it just open up the terminal. Now download the latest NetworkManager, in case you need to reinstall it if WICD doesn't work
sudo apt-get install -d --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome

Then to install it
sudo apt-get install wicd-gtk

And now you need to uninstall NetworkManager:
sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager-gnome network-manager

Now you can find WICD in your menu Start WICD, find the network you want to use and enter the information needed, password, encryption, etcetera and choose Automatically Connect to this network. You should be good to go!

WICD may also be available in Ubuntu Update Manager so you can look there first but it is important to uninstall Network Manager completely to prevent conflicts!!

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not address my problem. My issue is getting the rt5390sta driver to pick up the wireless device. Also, wicd not only does not solve the problem, it is more of a headache than network-manager in 13.04 and 13.10 because of the systray issue. I'd like to keep using network-manager. What I need is a way to discover why modprobe rt5390sta, while it loads the module, does not connect to the device.