# wifi signal fluctuates and disconnects

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

- Version Of Ubuntu-14.04(64 bit)
- Laptop Maker: Dell
- Laptop Model: Inspiron 1525
- wifi router: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] (32 bit)

wifi signal fluctuates and disconnects frequently. Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/295035/wifi-keeps-disconnecting-and-extremely-slow-at-low-signal-ubuntu-13-04?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

1) Connect computer via Ethernet

2) run **sudo apt-get update** in terminal

3) restart the computer

4) run **sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade** in terminal

5) restart computer

Did this fix the problem?

Comment: Any documentation that a distribution upgrade (away from the **LTS 14.04**, btw) will solve this?

Comment: Trying to run a 14.10 (or newer) live iso/dvd/usb and testing the WiFi there would be a much better idea, no need to destroy your currently installed 14.04 on a hunch.

Comment: Nothing has changed after executing both commands.
Wifi net work still fluctuate